# New page with textblock latex

Tags: page-breaking, minipage

I want the text to go to the second page when the first one is full. 
This because when I write in the second block and this is full I can't continue to a new page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[portuguese,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[
margin=1.5cm,
include foot,
footskip=10pt,
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\begin{textblock}{3}(1.0, 0.55)
\lipsum[1]
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{11.3}(6,0.55)
\lipsum[2]
\end{textblock}

end{document}
```

Comment: As you already tagged this question: minipages cannot be broken across pages. Perhaps you should try to explain what exactly it is you are trying to achieve, then perhaps we can find a suitable solution.

Comment: the only thing the `textblock` environments are doing are stopping page breaking. the default behaviour is of course to do what you ask, to flow text to the next page one one is full.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to use a `longtable` with a single column instead of a textbox, if you are trying to have control over the shape and size of the text.  A `longtable` will automatically continue onto another page.

Comment: Cells/rows of a `longtable` (and other multi-page tabular environments) cannot be broken across pages.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thank you!  Yes, this is true.  However, one could organize the text into multiple rows, and eventually get the desired result.  I don't think it is the _best_ option, but it is an option.